# Most efficient way to do this array insertion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of objects sorted by created_at  (which is of course a Time object)

I have a hash of objects which looks like

```
{
 time_in_integer1 => object1,
 time_in_integer2 => object2,
 time_in_integer3 => object3,
 .... 
}
```

I would like to insert object1, 2, 3 into the array in the most efficient manner, sorted by comparing the created_at with the keys in the hash.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: By keeping the initial array sorted I guess??

Comment: Can you clarify some things for me? You have an array of objects, each of which respond to `created_at`, by which they are sorted. You then have a hash of objects that do (not?) respond to `created_at`, but are unsorted and keyed by a unix timestamp. You then wish to insert those objects into the array, and maintain the array's sorted order. Is this all correct?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - thanks! The objects in the hash have created_at, but I do not want to use those to compare, but i want to use the keyed timestamp. The end array should maintain a sorted order (by the original array's created and the hash keyed timestamps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/134477#599091.

Comment: Please include an example and/or excerpt to "bare links"; otherwise consider a comment instead. This will make the reply more useful. Thanks! (Titles are also nice)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
my_array = (my_array + my_hash.values).sort_by {|obj| obj.created_at }
```